# How to run a null_resource in terraform at the start of the script

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I have a use case where I am taking all variables from locals in terraform as shown below, but before that, I want to run a null_resource block which will run a python script and update all the data into the local's file.

So my use case in simple words is to execute a null_resource block at the start of the terraform script and then run all the other resource blocks

My current code sample is as follows:

```
// executing script for populating data in app_config.json
resource "null_resource" "populate_data" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python3 scripts/data_populate.py"
  }
}


// reading data variables from app_config.json file
locals {
  config_data = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/app_config.json"))
}
```

How do I achieve that? All I have tried is adding a triggers command inside locals as follows but even that did not work.

```
locals {
  triggers = {
    order = null_resource.populate_data.id
  }
  
  config_data = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/app_config.json"))
}
```

Comment: You should wrap the terraform commands in a shell script that triggers the python script before running the actual terraform command. What you are trying to achieve is not what / how terraform is supposed to be used. Unless you explain in more detail what the script does, how the data it generates interacts with the rest of the deployment, what resources depend on it, etc.

Comment: you meant o say there is no way I can execute a null_resource block at the start of the terraform script as that's my use case?

Comment: There is a way, trigger the null_resource based on the timestamp and then add a depends_on relation to each an every resource such that they wait for the null_resource to complete. Not ideal or fun. You should not do that. The preferred way would be to  either wrap a script around it or create a custom data source for the python script and then have explicit dependencies on that script output, instead of writing to a file and reading from the file at some other place.

Comment: You can do all of this in a significantly easier way with the external data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source

Answer (score 3):

You can use `depends_on`

```
resource "null_resource" "populate_data" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python3 scripts/data_populate.py"
  }
}


// reading data variables from app_config.json file
locals {
  depends_on = [null_resource.populate_data]
  config_data = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/app_config.json"))
}
```

Now `locals` will get executed after `populate_data` always.

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is not a feature of `locals` to have a `depends_on` statement there that actually causes a depends_on relation and does not just define a local variable named `depends_on`. This simply does not work as intended.